# Изменение изображения внутри кнопки при нажатии и наведения курсора

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте, в своём словаре ресурсов имею такой код:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="close_button_template" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse>
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Image.png"/>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Как оформить триггер, что бы при нажатии и наведении мыши на кнопку изменялись изображения непосредственно внутри эллипса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ControlTemplate x:Key="close_button_template" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse>
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush x:Name="PART_ImageBrush" ImageSource="Image.png"/>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="PART_ImageBrush" Property="ImageSource" Value="ImageWhenMouseOver.png" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="PART_ImageBrush" Property="ImageSource" Value="ImageWhenPressed.png" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>`

Answer (score 0):

VisualStudio 2017 "Blank App"

XAML

```
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="400,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.258,-5" Click="Button_Click" Height="80" Width="80"/>
```

C# (Set the original image in the properties of the button: right-click -> Brush -> image)

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Images/timerg.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) };

    }
```

or C#

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            Uri u = new Uri("ms-appx:/Images/timer.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            bmp.UriSource = u;
            // NOTE: change starts here
            Image i = new Image();
            i.Source = bmp;
            button1.Content = i;
    }
```